# How to change a methode from an interface

Tags: java, list, interface

I want to create a class called CustomList. In my class I have to implement the interface List. After implementing the interface I need to change some signitures of the mehtodes so that I can work with it. When I change the signitures I am getting error messages. So the question is what can I do so that my code works.

The code is like the following:

```
public class CustomList implements List<Member>{

    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ListIterator;

    public class CustomList implements List {
        private List<Member> lom;
        public boolean add(Member m) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return lom.add(m);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to change all the signitures.

Comment: That would compile if you wrote implements List<Member>.

Answer (score 1):

you cant simply change the signature, thats what interface are there for: to provide a unified contract among classes, so that every class implements exactly the same stuff. you can still **add** whatever you want to your class, though.